# sum of subqueries values

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT `stationcode`, 
(Select sum(pis.NOPKGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE R') AS PKG_R, (Select sum(pis.WTQTLS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE R') AS WT_R,
(Select sum(pis.ERNGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE R') AS ERNG_R,
(Select sum(pis.NOPKGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE P') AS PKG_P, (Select sum(pis.WTQTLS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE P') AS WT_P,
(Select sum(pis.ERNGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE P') AS ERNG_P,
(Select sum(pis.NOPKGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE S') AS PKG_S, (Select sum(pis.WTQTLS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE S') AS WT_S,
(Select sum(pis.ERNGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE S') AS ERNG_S,
(Select sum(pis.NOPKGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE L') AS PKG_L, (Select sum(pis.WTQTLS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE L') AS WT_L,
(Select sum(pis.ERNGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE L') AS ERNG_L
,SUM(PKG_R+PKG_P+PKG_S+PKG_L) AS TOTAL_PKGS
FROM `station` WHERE Parcels = 'TRUE'
```

The query above is showing this error:

> Unknown column 'PKG_R' in 'field list'

Comment: Please include the DB schema in the question

Comment: for taking sum you have to do group by!!

Answer (score 0):

You may not use the alias directly in single query. you can use those alias outside only as like below.

```
   SELECT stationcode,SUM(PKG_R+PKG_P+PKG_S+PKG_L) AS TOTAL_PKGS FROM (SELECT stationcode, 
(Select sum(pis.NOPKGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE R') AS PKG_R, 
(Select sum(pis.WTQTLS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE R') AS WT_R,
(Select sum(pis.ERNGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE R') AS ERNG_R,
(Select sum(pis.NOPKGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE P') AS PKG_P, 
(Select sum(pis.WTQTLS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE P') AS WT_P,
(Select sum(pis.ERNGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE P') AS ERNG_P,
(Select sum(pis.NOPKGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE S') AS PKG_S, 
(Select sum(pis.WTQTLS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE S') AS WT_S,
(Select sum(pis.ERNGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE S') AS ERNG_S,
(Select sum(pis.NOPKGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE L') AS PKG_L, 
(Select sum(pis.WTQTLS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE L') AS WT_L,
(Select sum(pis.ERNGS) from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE L') AS ERNG_L
FROM station WHERE Parcels = 'TRUE' ) A
GROUP BY stationcode
```

Comment: This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "FROM" at position 1866)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "FROM" at position 1866) THIS IS ERROR SHOWING

Comment: remove single quote in 'Station'

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM station WHERE Parcels = 'TRUE' ) A
GROUP BY stationcode' at line 14 this error is showing

Answer (score 0):

if `stationcode` returns just one row then you can try this:

```
SELECT `stationcode`, PKG_R, WT_R, ERNG_R, PKG_P, WT_P, ERNG_P, PKG_S, WT_S, ERNG_S, PKG_L, WT_L, ERNG_L , SUM(PKG_R+PKG_P+PKG_S+PKG_L) AS TOTAL_PKGS
FROM
(
    (Select sum(pis.NOPKGS) AS PKG_R from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE R') a,
    (Select sum(pis.WTQTLS)  AS WT_R from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE R') b,
    (Select sum(pis.ERNGS)  AS ERNG_R from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE R') c,
    (Select sum(pis.NOPKGS)  AS PKG_P from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE P') d, 
    (Select sum(pis.WTQTLS) AS WT_P from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE P') e,
    (Select sum(pis.ERNGS) AS ERNG_P from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE P') f,
    (Select sum(pis.NOPKGS) AS PKG_S from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE S') g, 
    (Select sum(pis.WTQTLS) AS WT_S from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE S') h,
    (Select sum(pis.ERNGS) AS ERNG_S from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE S') i,
    (Select sum(pis.NOPKGS) AS PKG_L from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE L') j, 
    (Select sum(pis.WTQTLS) AS WT_L from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE L') k,
    (Select sum(pis.ERNGS) AS ERNG_L from pis where pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' and pis.parcelstn = station.stationcode and pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE L') l,
    `station`
)
WHERE Parcels = 'TRUE'
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'station.stationcode' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this query using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT stationcode, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE R' THEN pis.NOPKGS ELSE 0 END) AS PKG_R,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE R' THEN pis.WTQTLS ELSE 0 END) AS WT_R,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE R' THEN pis.ERNGS ELSE 0 END) AS ERNG_R,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE P' THEN pis.NOPKGS ELSE 0 END) AS PKG_P,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE P' THEN pis.WTQTLS ELSE 0 END) AS WT_P,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE P' THEN pis.ERNGS ELSE 0 END) AS ERNG_P,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE S' THEN pis.NOPKGS ELSE 0 END) AS PKG_S,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE S' THEN pis.WTQTLS ELSE 0 END) AS WT_S,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE S' THEN pis.ERNGS ELSE 0 END) AS ERNG_S,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE L' THEN pis.NOPKGS ELSE 0 END) AS PKG_L,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE L' THEN pis.WTQTLS ELSE 0 END) AS WT_L,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pis.BKDSCALE = 'SCALE L' THEN pis.ERNGS ELSE 0 END) AS ERNG_L,
       SUM(pis.NOPKGS) AS total_packages
FROM sstation s LEFT JOIN
     pis
     ON pis.parcelstn = s.stationcode AND
        pis.prcldate = '2018-11-28' AND
        pis.DKDSCALE IN ('SCALE R', 'SCALE S', 'SCALE P', 'SCALE L')
WHERE Parcels = 'TRUE' 
GROUP BY stationcode;
```